# How to set split() start and end delimiter?

Tags: python-3.x

```
[(0,
  '0.011*"people" + 0.009*"christian" + 0.008*"god" + 0.008*"law" + '
  '0.006*"believe" + 0.005*"question" + 0.005*"man" + 0.005*"life" + '
  '0.005*"time" + 0.005*"write"'),
 (1,
  '0.014*"organization" + 0.013*"group" + 0.012*"image" + 0.010*"university" + '
  '0.009*"program" + 0.008*"newsletter" + 0.007*"graphic" + '
  '0.007*"information" + 0.007*"file" + 0.006*"box"'),
 (2,
  '0.015*"write" + 0.015*"organization" + 0.014*"article" + 0.012*"year" + '
  '0.008*"university" + 0.007*"team" + 0.007*"time" + 0.006*"game" + '
  '0.006*"give" + 0.006*"kid"'),
 (3,
  '0.049*"space" + 0.009*"year" + 0.008*"publish" + 0.006*"aerospace" + '
  '0.006*"news" + 0.006*"technical" + 0.005*"satellite" + 0.005*"activity" + '
  '0.005*"membership" + 0.005*"system"')]
```

[image: Text_file: topics.txt]How do I set the delimeter for the text file shown in the image? I want it to split into four separate text files. What and how should I give the start and end delimiter in the *if()* as can be seen in the code?. The text file has four separate parts 0,1,2,3. I am trying to write all the parts into separate text file.

```
`with open('topics.txt','r') as fo:
    op=''
    start=0
    cntr = 1
    for x in fo.read().split("\n"):
        if (x==''):
            if (start==1):
                with open(str(cntr) + '.txt','w') as opf:
                    opf.write(op)
                    opf.close()
                    op=''
                    cntr+=1
            else:
                start=1
        else:
   if (op==''):
                op = x
            else:
                op = op + '\n' + x
    fo.close()`
```

Comment: Could you give the image you posted as text? I'll try and figure something out

Comment: Is this a `list`? Then each `tuple` inside is an element of the list, which can be accessed as `list[index]`.

Comment: It is a text file output from a topic modelling program. Each part are keywords of a dominant topic in the docs, so I am trying to put the keywords in separate file for each dominant topic.

Answer (score 1):

If what you posted above is literally your text file, then this should give you each tuple separately.

I'm just using the regular expressions library. The pattern is just look for a left paren ( and run of anything that isn't a right paren, and then a right paren. Super simple.

```
import re
foo = """[(0,\n blahblahblah), (1,\n asdfasdf), (2,\n ghhgghiegiegieh)]"""

pat = r'\([^\)]+\)'
matches = re.findall(pat, foo)

['(0,\n blahblahblah)', '(1,\n asdfasdf)', '(2,\n ghhgghiegiegieh)']
```

If you want to separate out the numbers you can do that easily by spliting and striping out the extra stuff:

```
[i[1:-1].split(',\n')[1].strip() for i in matches]
#['blahblahblah', 'asdfasdf', 'ghhgghiegiegieh']
```

Then you can write them to whatever file you like.

Comment: I am sorry for being very dumb but could you please elaborate a bit more? I have also edited with the text file in my question. However the texts are actually in a text file in my local drive and I will have to read it from there

Comment: Sure! In place for where foo is, just replace that with:
```foo = open('filename.txt', 'r').read()```
That should provide you a string which can be fed to everything else. You pretty much have all the mechanics of what you need from the piece of code you already wrote.